Counting the Number of Points in Each Box
I am working with the R programming language.
Suppose I have the following dataset:
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42) 
heights <- rnorm(100, mean=170, sd=10) 
weights <- rnorm(100, mean=65, sd=15) 

data <- data.frame(heights, weights)

ggplot(data, aes(x = heights, y = weights)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Scatterplot of Heights and Weights",
       x = "Height (cm)",
       y = "Weight (kg)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(floor(min(data$heights)), ceiling(max(data$heights)), by = 5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(floor(min(data$weights)), ceiling(max(data$weights)), by = 5))


Suppose I look at every "box" that can be made of size 5x5 - I manually drew this on top of the original plot:

My Question: I am interested in counting the number of points contained in each of these boxes.
I first defined the max boundaries of each variable:
max_height <- max(data$heights)
max_weight <- max(data$weights)

height_breaks <- seq(0, max_height, by=5)
weight_breaks <- seq(0, max_weight, by=5)

Then using the expand.grid() function, I tried to make a data frame that contains each of these boxes using the expand.grid function:
combinations <- expand.grid(height = seq_along(height_breaks)[-length(height_breaks)],
                            weight = seq_along(weight_breaks)[-length(weight_breaks)])

interval_label <- function(breaks, index) {
  paste0("(", breaks[index], "-", breaks[index + 1], ")")
}

combinations$height_interval <- mapply(interval_label, list(height_breaks), combinations$height)
combinations$weight_interval <- mapply(interval_label, list(weight_breaks), combinations$weight)

height_weight_boxes <- combinations[, c("height_interval", "weight_interval")]

Using some further manipulations, I made 4 separate columns for the min/max of each variable:
  library(dplyr)
transformed_df <- height_weight_boxes %>%
    mutate(
        box_number = row_number(), 
        min_height = as.numeric(sub("\\((.*?)-.*", "\\1", height_interval)), 
        max_height = as.numeric(sub(".*-(.*)\\)", "\\1", height_interval)), 
        min_weight = as.numeric(sub("\\((.*?)-.*", "\\1", weight_interval)), 
        max_weight = as.numeric(sub(".*-(.*)\\)", "\\1", weight_interval)) 
    ) %>%
    select(box_number, min_height, max_height, min_weight, max_weight)

This now looks like this:
 box_number min_height max_height min_weight max_weight
          1          0          5          0          5
          2          5         10          0          5
          3         10         15          0          5
          4         15         20          0          5
          5         20         25          0          5
          6         25         30          0          5

In the final step, I now want to use this reference frame (transformed_df) to query the original data frame and count how many points are in each box. Logically, I thought of doing this by literally counting how many points are contained within the boundaries of each box:
library(dplyr)

count_points_in_box <- function(min_height, max_height, min_weight, max_weight, data) {
    data %>%
        filter(heights >= min_height, heights < max_height,
               weights >= min_weight, weights < max_weight) %>%
        nrow()
}

final <- transformed_df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(count = count_points_in_box(min_height, max_height, min_weight, max_weight, data))

In the end, I tried to check if the box counts match the original data:
> sum(final$count)
[1] 97
> nrow(data)
[1] 100

While the results are close, I think I might have done something wrong as the counts don't match completely. Can someone please help me correct this?

count_points_in_box() only includes points < max_height and < max_weight, but you define the boxes to end at the max_height and max_weight. So the extremes are excluded.
I think this could be done more simply like:
library(tidyverse)
data |>
  count(heights = floor(heights/5)*5,
        weights = floor(weights/5)*5)  |>
  complete(heights = seq(0, max(heights), by = 5),
           weights = seq(0, max(weights), by = 5),
           fill = list(n = 0)) |>
  arrange(weights, heights) |>
  mutate(box_number = row_number()) 


@ Jon Spring: Thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to add the min/max of weight and height for each box in the final answer?

The boxes here were assigned rounding down to multiple of 5, so that's the min and the max is 5 more.

I think I was able to modify your answer by adding more DPLYR arguments to get it in the way I wanted. I accepted your answer as the official answer! :) thank you so much!
